# Apply CSS to all the elements inside TH tag

Tags: html, css

I would like to check if there is any easiest way of doing the below task

I want to apply font-size:10px to the TD tag of the table, but also it should override all the elements inside TH font-size to 10px, no matter what tag it has like  or  or  or anything.

Your help would appreciated
Please check below code for reference

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
}

th {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.table_tr td {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.table_span span {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.table_div div {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>HTML Table with Inputs, Span, and Div</title>
  <style>
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      padding: 8px;
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    th {
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }
    
    .table_tr td {
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    
    .table_span span {
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    
    .table_div div {
      font-size: 18px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table>

    <head>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>

      <body>
        <tr class="table_tr">
          <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter name"></td>
          <td><input type="email" placeholder="Enter email"></td>
          <td>
            <span class="table_span">Some text</span>
            <div class="table_div">Some content</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter name"></td>
          <td><input type="email" placeholder="Enter email"></td>
          <td>
            <span class="table_span">Some text</span>
            <div class="table_div">Some content</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter name"></td>
          <td><input type="email" placeholder="Enter email"></td>
          <td>
            <span class="table_span">Some text</span>
            <div class="table_div">Some content</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: You are missing thead opening tag in your code and please check this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/cx7tmyvj/  is that you want?

Comment: What more tag you want to use inside th tag?

Comment: @Leothelion - the ask is i want to apply CSS to TD tag which should also apply to inside DIV and SPAN or if any other tags present, basically it should override the style of child elements based on TD

Comment: In your question you said under the th and now you are saying td but child you are talking about are under the body tag? sorry but you want to change the font size of all the tag under body section or td section?

Comment: Updated the ask with TD, `sorry but you want to change the font size of all the tag under body section or td section? `- Yes

Comment: Then just do `body { font-size: 12px; }`?

Comment: It is really not clear what you actually want know, please edit the question an clarify it in there. If you want to overwrite the font size for any descendant elements inside the TH, that might have a different font size set, then you might want something like `th * { font-size: 12px !important; }` perhaps.

Comment: th * { font-size: 12px !important; } this is not working if inside th span or div tag has diff font size

Comment: th or td it really matters, the whole point is, inside th/td if there are any span or div or any other tags there which are having different different font sizes, it should take only the th/td's font size not the child elements.

Comment: Why it is marked as `-1`

Comment: Ok got your point. Please check this fiddle. is this what you want?  https://jsfiddle.net/h1jbuqyv/

Comment: @Leothelion Tons of thanks, yeah this is what I am looking for....
Unfortunately, I cant vote it, but you made my day

Comment: Ok. If this helps you i am posting as answer then you can accept so it might help other user with same issue.

Comment: _"th * { font-size: 12px !important; } this is not working if inside th span or div tag has diff font size"_ - what are you talking about? Replacing `body *` in the solution Leo provided, with `th *, td *` achieves the exact same result. (Yes, of course you need to add the part for the `td`, if you want it to work in those as well, and not only inside the `th`.)

Comment: @CBroe i think she wants to change the font color of all tag under body like div,span,td,th so i put that rather than putting all css with different tags.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all there is typo error of thead opening tag, Second If you want to apply particular css to all child element of your fiddle/code then you can simply use that css on `body *`. like this

```
 body *{
      font-size:10px !important;
    }
```

You can also check working codepan here where font-size is applying to all tags like td,th,div and span etc.

Codepan :

```css
table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      padding: 8px;
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    th {
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }
    
    .table_tr td {
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    
    .table_span span {
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    
    .table_div div {
      font-size: 18px;
    }
    body *{
      font-size:10px !important;
    }
```

```html
<table>

    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>

      <body>
        <tr class="table_tr">
          <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter name"></td>
          <td><input type="email" placeholder="Enter email"></td>
          <td>
            <span class="table_span">Some text</span>
            <div class="table_div">Some content</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter name"></td>
          <td><input type="email" placeholder="Enter email"></td>
          <td>
            <span class="table_span">Some text</span>
            <div class="table_div">Some content</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter name"></td>
          <td><input type="email" placeholder="Enter email"></td>
          <td>
            <span class="table_span">Some text</span>
            <div class="table_div">Some content</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

As commented before your HTML and CSS has several issues

Make sure all elements are closed/nested correctly:
Like `<thead>` but also `<tbody>`

Before overriding any style rules you should also check the more general (so inherited by child/descendant elements) rules – maybe you can remove some:

```CSS
    .table_span span {
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    
    .table_div div {
      font-size: 18px;
    }
```

don't select anything – these rules translate to:
find element with class `.table_span` and select a `span` child element inside. But the used span elements have this class. So it should be:

```CSS
    .table_span{
      font-size: 14px;
    }
```

or (not recommended – since unnecessarily specific)

```CSS
    span.table_span{
      font-size: 14px;
    }
```

From your description you want your table font size to be normalized to 10px.
Therefore, just remove these rules and set a general font-size to your table.

```css
/* general rule for all tables */
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height:1.2em;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
}

th {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

/* table cell child/decendant elements */
th *,
td *{
  font-family:inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="table_tr">
      <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter name"></td>
      <td><input type="email" placeholder="Enter email"></td>
      <td>
        <span class="table_span">Some text</span>
        <div class="table_div">Some content</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter name"></td>
      <td><input type="email" placeholder="Enter email"></td>
      <td>
        <span class="table_span">Some text</span>
        <div class="table_div">Some content</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter name"></td>
      <td><input type="email" placeholder="Enter email"></td>
      <td>
        <span class="table_span">Some text</span>
        <div class="table_div">Some content</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Rule of thumb: define your styles **from general rule to exception**

If you need too many overriding rules (i.e exceptions by requiring `!important` or nested selectors) you should consider to simplify your main rules.

You may also have loads of other tables or elements on your page - so be careful with to global style rules.

If you're uncertain if you may need some styles just disable them via comments like so:

```css
body {
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 18px, line-height:1.4em;
}


/* general rule for all tables */

table {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

th,
td {
  font-family: inherit;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
}

th {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}


/* table cell child/decendant elements */

th *,
td * {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
}


/* we don't need these class selctor - do we? */


/*
.table_tr td{
  font-size: 12px;
}

.table_span  {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.table_div {
   font-size: 18px;
}
*/
```

```html
<h1>Font size not inherited to table</h1>
<p>One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin.</p>

<p>He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted his head a little he could see his brown belly, slightly domed and divided by arches into stiff sections. The bedding was hardly able to cover it and seemed ready to slide off any moment.</p>


<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="table_tr">
      <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter name"></td>
      <td><input type="email" placeholder="Enter email"></td>
      <td>
        <span class="table_span">Some text</span>
        <div class="table_div">Some content</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter name"></td>
      <td><input type="email" placeholder="Enter email"></td>
      <td>
        <span class="table_span">Some text</span>
        <div class="table_div">Some content</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter name"></td>
      <td><input type="email" placeholder="Enter email"></td>
      <td>
        <span class="table_span">Some text</span>
        <div class="table_div">Some content</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```